# 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access - mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

OK, so I have searched for an answer everywhere but this doesn't seem to be a similar issue others are having.

From .htaccess

`RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-(.*)\.html$ index\.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]`

The above rule is working for this URL:

https://www.example.com/seo-page-name-p-341.html

But this one gives me the 403 error:

https://www.example.com/seo-page-name-p-341:6662cd9f4515a07efd25ef413b81846f.html

Here is the page without rewrite:

https://www.example.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=341:6662cd9f4515a07efd25ef413b81846f

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!
David

Comment: You have a colon(:) in the URL that gives you 403, but not in the RegEx. Also I don't think you're allowed to use a colon. Try another character instead like a hyphen(-) and see if works.

Comment: Sorry, I posted wrong rewrite rule (now edited in the original question). Yes, one I posted would have been incorrect, but that wasn't the problem. Here is the rule I was actually using and still failing:

RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-(.*).html$ index\.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

As you can see, the regex catches everything after -p- and didn't need to single out parts. In my solution, however, I needed to single them out and then reassemble to feed it back to PHP that does expect colon.

Comment: You were right about the colon, though, thanks - please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, after further research, I discovered that colon is a disallowed character on Windows version of Apache, due to NTFS conventions. I instead opted for using a plus '+' character. I simply rewrote the corresponding PHP in the shopping cart software to output:

https://www.example.com/seo-page-name-p-341+6662cd9f4515a07efd25ef413b81846f.html

Then, in .htaccess, I added:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-([^\+]+)\+(.*)\.html$ index\.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=$2:$3&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

This splits the value and reassembles it with a colon, to feed it back to PHP that expects it. As in:

https://www.example.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=341:6662cd9f4515a07efd25ef413b81846f

Hopefully, I will only need to do this on Windows (test) server and should be unnecessary on the Unix Apache, come deployment time.